# HTTPS request not working on ios simualtor

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, fetch, expo

i finished coding my app in react-native and everything worked fine in expo app (i could log in and use the app) but when i built the app and started it in xcode, it seems like my HTTPS requests don't work. It's stuck in loading mode and the request doesnt work.

Heres the example request:

```
export const fetchUserLoginToken = async (props) => {
    let userCredentials = await fetch('https://xxxx', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": `${props.username}`,
            "password": `${props.password}`
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            return data
        })
    return userCredentials
}
```

Any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the enpoint actually ```https```, Android and iOS don't allow http requests in production. So it's most likely that the endpoint isn't https.

Comment: Yes it is, it worked before in expo app but now it doesnt work anywhere :(